# VP6 decoder SDK

Tags: video, codec, vp8, onvp8

Is On2/Google VP8 decoder, backward compatible with VP6? Or can VP6 video stream be decoder using VP8 decoder?

Also is their and SDK for VP6 decoding?

Is there any VP6 decoder for a commercial product (I cannot use open source)?

I tried the On2 Flix SDK, but it is for encoding only.

Comment: I'm looking for a good one, too...

Answer (score 0):

VP8 is not backwards compatible with VP6.